# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. при запуске проекта в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle

При запуске проекта выходят следующие ошибки:

```
 Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.androidx.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/androidx/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.androidx.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/androidx/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Gradle привожу ниже:

dependencies {

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.androidx.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.androidx.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0"
```

}

Никак не могу понять в чем ошибка, искал на форумах, не одна рекомендация не помогла (Офлайн режим градл не был включен, прокси так же, обычно дело в них было у людей с схожей проблемой)
Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? Буду крайне признателен за совет)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку нашел и исправил, вдруг кому-то пригодится:
заменил `com.androidx.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` на  `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version` и `'com.androidx.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3`  на `"androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"`, все скомпилировалось)